# Installer for Java Applications

Tags: java, deployment, jar, installation

I need to create an installer for my java desktop application. I don't like to code an installer by hand. is there anyway I can create an installer for Java applications?

Comment: You know... you could've just renamed your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021015/my-java-programming-style-vs-c-net-programming-style)...

Comment: I needed to share my knowledge on this. Thats why I created this question. My answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pack Jacket software: 
      This is a freeware with a simple GUI. Available to download from sourceforge. This file is capable of creating installers with extensions .exe, .jar and much more. The complete tutorial is available in youtube. Just search "How to make installer for regular java project" in youtube and the first result, you will find the tutorial (I tried to paste the link here, but stackoverflow didn't allow it :( ).
2. IZPack: 
      IZpack doesn't have any GUI, just some files. You have to do it manually. It takes xml files as parameters which instruct it how to create the installer. The tutorial for using IZpack is [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/deploy-your-java-application-with-izpack-installer/). I am using IZpack and personally I like it more than pack jacket.

There are more apps for creating these installers, but according to my knowledge these are the most famous because I have seen these installers in number of applications I have used.

Hope you can make your work easy by reading this :)

Comment: *"Hope you can make your work easy by reading this"*  This answer is neither the best option for a desktop app., nor a comprehensive summary of alternatives.  I am tempted to -1 it.  (But no, I've down-voted nothing, as yet.)

Answer (score 2):

If your looking to create an installer for windows applications check out [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). For linux based machines, I'd just got with the regular tar.gz file and a README file.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvience john, I tried to share my knowledge by posting my own answer. But an error occurred, as a result, my question got submitted, without the answer. :)

Comment: Anyway, IZPACK and pack jacket can be used in any platform :)

Answer (score 0):

> ..installer for my java desktop application.

Deliver it over the net using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..